# Why is MySQL string not case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to solve [a query challenge: print out all the names of the cities that do not start with a vowel](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-9/problem). I used the following condition that was meant only for lower vowels but the MySQL engine was working even for upper case vowels too. Why is that?

Click [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/master/challenges/weather-observation-station-9/download_testcases) to get the sample input.

This is my solution:

```
select distinct city from station where left(city, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

I checked the data, there are cities like `Arlington` that start with an uppercase vowel but still is getting filtered out by the where clause that only concerns the lowercase vowels.

Comment: The default for MySQL is case-insensitivity.  You should learn about collations and `binary`.

Comment: You need to check your MySQL table and column Collations and Character Sets are Case Sensitive , ie, they end in `_cs` (`whatever_cs`, `latin1_general_cs`, etc.)